# Rails split sentence into separate words but substitute certain words

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

**What the goal is**

```
<span>I</span> 
<span>helped</span>
<span>the</span>
<span class="highlighted">Adidas</span>
<span class="highlighted">brand</span>
<span>rebuild</span>
<span>their</span>
<span>design</span>
<span>system</span>
```

---

Got a Rails project I'm working on. I've got data that forms a sentence like so:

```
sentence = 'I helped Adidas rebuild their design system'
```

I can separate the words with `sentence.split(/\W+/)` and I get:

```
[I] [helped] [Adidas] [rebuild] [their] [design] [system]
```

But I would like to highlight the word `Adidas` by wrapping it in a class.

Sometimes that highlighted word can be a combination of words like `Adidas brand`

For that I tried doing:

```
sentence.sub(sentenceHighlight, "<span>#{sentenceHighlight}</span>")
```

Which gives me:

```
I helped the <span>Adidas brand</span> rebuild their design system
```

While that works fine I still need each of the words to be separate like in the example above.

Does anyone know how I can combine the two methods nicely in a clean code?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want the goal to be, do you want an array of strings, an array of arrays, or do you just want a string with the brackets? it looks like you want the span elements to be outside of the array.

Comment: @LasseSviland The goal is I suppose to be able to loop through each of the words and wrap them in span tags with the highlighted words in a with a separate css class. I should have been more clear. So `<span>I</span> <span>helped</span> <span>the</span> <span class="highlighted">Adidas</span> <span class="highlighted">brand</span> <span>rebuild</span> <span>their</span> <span>design</span> <span>system</span>

`

Comment: Edited the question to reflect this comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
sentence = 'I helped Adidas brand rebuild their design system'
words  = ["Adidas", "brand"]

sentence = sentence.split(/\W+/)
sentence.map! do |word|
  words.include?(word) ? "<span class='highlight'>#{word}</span>" : "<span>#{word}</span>"
end


puts sentence 
# => 
<span>I</span>
<span>helped</span>
<span class='highlight'>Adidas</span>
<span class='highlight'>brand</span>
<span>rebuild</span>
<span>their</span>
<span>design</span>
<span>system</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I pasted your exact code and it gave me:
`["I", "helped", "", "", "rebuild", "their", "design", "system"]`

Comment: I think you must have done something wrong, here is a fidle http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/dcf43/2

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method:

```
highlight('You searched for: rails', 'rails')
# => You searched for: <mark>rails</mark>

highlight('You searched for: rails', /for|rails/)
# => You searched <mark>for</mark>: <mark>rails</mark>

highlight('You searched for: ruby, rails, dhh', 'actionpack')
# => You searched for: ruby, rails, dhh

highlight('You searched for: rails', ['for', 'rails'], highlighter: '<em>\1</em>')
# => You searched <em>for</em>: <em>rails</em>

highlight('You searched for: rails', 'rails', highlighter: '<a href="search?q=\1">\1</a>')
# => You searched for: <a href="search?q=rails">rails</a>

highlight('You searched for: rails', 'rails') { |match| link_to(search_path(q: match, match)) }
# => You searched for: <a href="search?q=rails">rails</a>
```

In your case:

```
highlight('I helped Adidas rebuild their design system', ['Adidas'], highlighter: '<span class="highlighted">\1 brand</span>')
 # => I helped the <span>Adidas brand</span> rebuild their design system
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping out, your solutions already does the same thing as I posted initially: `sentence.sub(sentenceHighlight, "<span>#{sentenceHighlight}</span>")` I would like each of the words to still be wrapped in a separate span, check the updated question. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to understand why you would be splitting the sentence itself? Why not the other way around, you have the "highlights" as an array and you loop the highlight words, gsub'ing the sentence for each word, like:

```
sentence = 'I helped Adidas brand rebuild their design system'
highlights = ['adidas', 'brand']

highlights.each do |hl|
  sentence.gsub!(/\b#{hl}\b/i, "<span>#{hl}</span>")
end
puts sentence
  $ I helped <span>adidas</span> <span>brand</span> rebuild their design system
```

If you need the case from the original sentence use:

```
sentence.gsub!(/\b#{hl}\b/i) { |w_capture| "<span>#{w_capture}</span>" }
```

Since the highlights will be less words than the sentence itself it's also cheaper to loop them instead of all words in the sentence.

EDIT:

```
highlights = ['adidas', 'brand'] #lower case always
sentence = 'I helped Adidas brand rebuild their design system'
sentence.split(/\W+/).map { |w| highlights.include?(w.downcase) ? "<span class='class_1'>#{w} </span>" : "<span>#{w}</span>" }.join(' ') + "."
```

outputs:

```
=> "<span>I</span> <span>helped</span> <span class='class_1'>Adidas</span> <span class='class_1'>brand</span> <span>rebuild</span> <span>their</span> <span>design</span> <span>system</span>."
```

Comment: Hey Micael, thanks for looking into this. I realised I initially wasn't clear enough with what I wanted. I updated the question to reflect this. So each of the words needs to be wrapped with the highlighted words distinguishable via a separate CSS class

Comment: Updated @SebastianGraz

Comment: Thank you Micael, that looks like a solid alternative, at this time it seems like Lasses solution works for what I need. If I find a bug and yours work better I will transfer the accepted answer to you. Ty

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
    sentence = 'I helped Adidas brand rebuild their design system'
    sentenceHighlight = 'Adidas brand'
    (sentence.split(/\W+/) - sentenceHighlight.split(/\W+/)).each{|s| sentence.sub!(s, "<span>#{s}</span>")}
    sentenceHighlight.split(/\W+/).each{|s| sentence.sub!(s, "<span class='highlighted'>#{s}</span>")}


sentence 
#=> "<span>I</span> <span>helped</span> <span class='highlighted'>Adidas</span> <span class='highlighted'>brand</span>  <span>rebuild</span> <span>their</span> <span>design</span> <span>system</span>"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is it possible to wrap the remaining words as well? But with the sentenceHighlight in a different tag or with a CSS class? Please check the updated question. Ty